# Overcoming MySQL limit of 2^32 rows in a MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, myisam

I want to create a MyISAM table in MySQL (tried various versions of 5.0.x and 5.1.x) which allows more than 2^32 rows. The way to achieve this is to get MySQL to use 8-byte instead of 4-byte row pointers.

Here's a quote from the MySQL manual:

> If you build MySQL with the --with-big-tables option, the row limitation is increased to 1.844E+19 rows. See Section 2.3.2, “Typical configure Options”. Binary distributions for Unix and Linux are built with this option.

Sounds simple, right? But I've tried various binary distributions for Linux x86_64, and also building MySQL from the source code with the "--with-big-tables" option. In every case I still can't get beyond the 2^32 limit. I create a table like thus:

`CREATE TABLE big (col int) MAX_ROWS=1099511627776`

And when I check the table status, it says:

`Create_options: max_rows=4294967295`

How do I escape 32-bit purgatory? Using InnoDB might solve the problem, but it performs a lot more slowly for the type of queries I'm running.

FYI, here's an important reference that didn't solve the problem:

http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000796.html

Comment: Are you sure that you legitimately need that many rows?

Comment: @Fosco: If he is dealing with it, assume he is.

Comment: Yes, I certainly need that many rows!

Answer (score 5):

I worked this out for myself, and the answer is both simple and absurd.

If you *leave out* the MAX_ROWS setting when creating a MyISAM table, then the table doesn't suffer from the 2^32 limit on rows. Instead the maximum number of rows is determined by the pointer size, which is itself determined by the global variable myisam_data_pointer_size.

By default, the myisam_data_pointer_size is 6 on modern builds of MySQL running on Linux/Unix, leading to a limit of 2^48 rows on tables with fixed row width (or 2^48 bytes on tables with dynamic rows). But you can also change it using something like:

```
SET GLOBAL myisam_data_pointer_size=5;
```

And check it using:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'myisam_data_pointer_size';
```

In a MyISAM table with fixed width rows, the maximum number of rows is equal to (2^(8* myisam_data_pointer_size))-1, given myisam_data_pointer_size at the time of table creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling mysql using --with-big-tables option, the row limitation is increased to (2^32)^2. Unfortunately this is the highest limit :)

Comment: But the problem is that this is not happening. It's staying at 2^32, even when compiling with that option (on x86_64, not that this should make a difference).

Comment: Another limitation is the size to 256TB but I don't think it's your case. I never tried to reach those limits. I'm pretty sure it's an engineering issue and you can avoid those limits.